# Python : download image from url but receiving HTTP Error 404

Tags: python

I'm trying to download an image from a website but I get a 404 error. I tried to add a user agent with no sucess.

Here is the code:

```
import requests
import shutil

with open(r'C:\Users\home\Desktop\urls.csv') as file:
    csv = []
    for row in file:
        csv.append(row.split(";"))


row = 0

while row < len(csv):
    r = requests.get(csv[row][0], stream=True, headers={'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    if r.status_code == 200:
        with open(r"C:\Users\home\Desktop\images\house" + str(row) + ".jpg", 'wb') as f:
            r.raw.decode_content = True
            shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)
    row +=1
```

The url is:

https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/toronto-curbed-8.jpg
replace example by cdn.icepop

Comment: I had no problem using requests.get() to download the example; in fact I didn't even need to set the user agent. Have you made sure that the url is correct, e.g with *print(csv[row][0])* before the download?

Comment: I modified your code to download the single url and it downloaded the file without any problems. That would suggest a problem with the CSV file or the way you're parsing it.

Comment: Weird. I keep getting 404 errors. I'm sure the URL are ok.

Comment: Maybe there's whitespace before the ';' in your file or something?

Comment: Yeah, It was a space added by excel. Thank you,